# Random vector - calculate expected value, variation, cov, $D^2 X$

Tags: probability

$$\begin{bmatrix}
X/Y & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{2}\\ 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Calculate $D^{2}X$, $E(X+Y)$, $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, $E(XY)$

**My take on task:**

$EX=\frac{1}{4}$

$EY=1*\frac{1}{4}+2*\frac{1}{4}+3*\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{9}{4}$

$E(X+Y)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{9}{4}=\frac{10}{4}$

$E(XY)=\frac{1}{2}$

$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-EXEY=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{16}=-\frac{1}{16}$

$D^{2}X=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{3}{16}$

Could anyone check if its right?

Also is there a website where I could fill out the table with numbers and get all those answers?

I need to practice this a lot and I don't want to spam this forum with same task.

Comment: $E(X+Y)=\frac{1}{4}(0+1)+\frac{1}{4}(1+2)+\frac{1}{2}(0+3) = 1/4 + 3/4 + 3/2 = 5/2$. Can you understand what I did and redo the calculations where there is dependence?

Comment: @cgss Is my $E(X+Y)$ wrong? We got same values so I am confused

Comment: You haven't defined anything here. What does the given matrix represent, what is D, how are X and Y defined? I would suggest a major rewrite of this problem.

Comment: @bob Its supposed to be table, but I don't know how to do them in latex so I made matrix instead.
This is how task looks on example test: https://imgur.com/rRbdsfw "random vector has a distribution given by a table:"

Comment: @fakerakerp Your sum is correct but your product isn't. You can easily see this since you found it greater than 2 but the only possible values are 0 and 2. What you wrote for the sum is correct because expectation is linear. But it's not multiplicative(unless the variables are independent) so your product is wrong. Give it another shot.

Comment: @cgss could you check main post? I edited E(XY) and cov(X,Y)

Comment: They are both correct now.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on this but finally I understand